# esttab estimations results do not have e(b) and e(V)

Tags: stata

I have been using the `estout` commands for quite some time now, but am now working on a couple of computers that are not connected to the internet. I have been getting the following error from the `esttab` command:

`current estimation results do not have e(b) and e(V)`

To test this with a simpler example, I tried to replicate the example here: http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/estpost.html#estpost101

I created a sample dataset as below:

```
price   mpg     rep78   foreign
1       3       1       1
2       3       1       1
3       3       1       2
4       3       2       3
5       3       2       5
6       3       2       8
7       3       3       13
8       3       3       21
9       3       3       34
```

And then ran the following commands as per the example:

```
estpost summarize price mpg rep78 foreign, listwise
esttab, cells("mean sd min max") nomtitle nonumber
```

I got the expected output with the `estpost` command, but got the aforementioned error when running `esttab`. I have uninstalled and reinstalled this package several times, using both a version downloaded onto another computer using `ssc install` and a version downloaded from http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/installation.html. I feel that I must be missing something obvious...any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I just checked with a colleague of mine, and it seems they have been inexplicably getting the same error recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me. I suspect faulty installation. Despite your best efforts, you may have previously installed versions of some or all of the programs in `estout` on your system.

In Stata, you need to check what Stata is seeing by typing commands such as

```
. which esttab, all
```

in every directory in which you work. If necessary, repeat for all the other command files in the package as named by `ssc desc estout`. You should be seeing one (and only one) version of each command, dates mostly in 2009 (`eststo` in 2008).

A wilder hypothesis is that `estout` has been broken by recent changes in Stata. This seems unlikely to me, but check the above first.

(UPDATE) OP reply reveals a nightmare scenario: old versions have been found that are difficult to remove. What to do?

- Look at the `adopath` command. In the first instance, just type `adopath`. Stata wants to install `estout` stuff in an `e` off whatever it labels `PLUS`. (If you are in the US, you probably want to say "off of".)
- One possibility is that you use `adopath` to reset `PLUS` to somewhere you have write access, preferably somewhere dedicated to programs alone. That's got implications for programs already in `PLUS`, which are now longer visible, so you need to add whatever is now `PLUS` as an extra place to look. The help for `adopath` explains how to do this.
- Another possibility is that Stata always looks in the current directory or folder for a user-written program before it looks in `PLUS` (unless you mess with that order, which I advise against). So, so long as programs you want are in the current directory, that should work. However, this would usually be considered poor style. Worse, as you change the working  directory, you need to copy programs to that directory.
- You may need to approach the administrators to delete the old stuff. It is hard to work with user-written programs for Stata if you don't have the right privileges.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Thanks. It appears, on the computers where it is not working, that there is a version from 2007 that I did not get rid of. Unfortunately, I do not have administrative privileges on these computers - is there a way to specify the directory in which Stata should be looking for the correct version?